# How to explode select option id and name in store method laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, explode

I want to get id and name from select option for insert in table
how do I get that?

My view blade :

```
<th>
  <select name="itemIdSelected" id="itemNameSelected" class="form-control nameItem" >
     <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true" >Select Item Name</option>
        @foreach($listItem as $item)
            <option value="{{ $item->item_id }}:{{$item->item_name}}">{{ $item->item_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
  </select>
</th>
```

My controller :

```
public function storeOrder(Request $request){
    $order = DB::table('order_item_master_model')->insert([
    'product_id' => $request -> itemIdSelected, // will return 15:Ben Top Biru, how do I get 15
    'customer_name' => $request -> customerName,
    'phone' => $request -> phone,
    'address' => $request -> address,
    'item_name' => $request -> itemIdSelected, // will return 15:Ben Top Biru, how do I get Ben Top Biru
    'qty' => $request -> qty,
    'uom' => $request -> uom,
    'item_price' => $request -> prc,
    'total_price' => $request -> totalPrice,
    'status' => $request -> status,
]);
    return redirect('orderProcess');
```

Here is my error :
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'product_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `order_item_master_model` (**`product_id`**, `customer_name`, `phone`, `address`, **`item_name`**, `qty`, `uom`, `item_price`, `total_price`, `status`) values (**15:Ben Top Biru**, dana, 081233, purwojersey, **15:Ben Top Biru**, 2, Liter, Rp. 4000, Rp. 8000, lunas))

How do I solve this error

Comment: why are you using id and name as the option value?? simply use id as the option value and use find to get the object of selected item and insert from the object.

Comment: because I need to get the name from select option and insert to database the id and the name of object @ zahid hasan emon

Comment: get the id from select, use that id to find the object and then use that object to get value. more easier and clean way than your current approach.

Comment: @rezairawan, did you try my answer below?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi yes I have tried, but giving this error 

"Trying to access array offset on value of type null"

Comment: Are you certain that you are passing both id and name in the format of id:name?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi Yes I want to post them to the database column product_id and item_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP function **explode()** like below:

```
public function storeOrder(Request $request){

    // Explode the ID and Name and put them in array respectively.
    $extracted = explode(":", $request -> itemIdSelected);

    $order = DB::table('order_item_master_model')->insert([
        'product_id' => $extracted[0], // Will return ID. 
        'customer_name' => $request -> customerName,
        'phone' => $request -> phone,
        'address' => $request -> address,
        'item_name' => $extracted[1], // Will return Name.
        'qty' => $request -> qty,
        'uom' => $request -> uom,
        'item_price' => $request -> prc,
        'total_price' => $request -> totalPrice,
        'status' => $request -> status,
    ]);

    return redirect('orderProcess');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the type / or size of the product_id column does not match the type / or size of the data you are inserting.
Check the type / or size of your product_id column.